# lab10.c:18:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token { ^ lab10.c:31:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token {

Tags: c

Getting this error:

> expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token on the first bracket after
>   the #include before the int main.

No clue why! Doing an assignment for an introductory programming course. It's due today so any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTETOBINARYPATTERN "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"

#define BYTETOBINARY(byte)  \
    (byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x40 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x20 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0) 

#define PRINTBIN(x) printf(BYTETOBINARYPATTERN, BYTETOBINARY(x));

#define ARRAYLEN 8

{
    unsigned char final = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        final >>= 1;
        if (p[i] & 1)
            final |= 0x80;
    }
    return final;
}

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
         if (b0 & 1)
             p[i] |= 1;
         else
             p[i] &= 0xFE;
         b0 >>= 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char myArray[ARRAYLEN];
    unsigned char b, newB;
    int i, seed;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &seed);
    srandom(seed);

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = random() % (255 + 1);
        printf("\nThe %dth random number is %d: ", i, myArray[i]);
        PRINTBIN(myArray[i]);
    }
    b = random() % (255 + 1);
    printf("\n\nThe original b0 is %d: ", b);
    PRINTBIN(b);
    printf("\n");

    setlsbs(myArray, b);
    printf("\n");
    printf("In the setlsbs function:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
        printf("The %dth random number with replaced least significant bit is %d: ", i, myArray[i]);
        PRINTBIN(myArray[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    newB = getlsbs(myArray);
    printf("\n");

    printf("In the getlsbs function:\n");
    for (i = ARRAYLEN - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("The %dth random number with replaced least significant bit is %d: ", i, myArray[i]);
        PRINTBIN(myArray[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("The b0 from 'myArray' is %d: ", newB);
    PRINTBIN(newB);
    printf("\n");
}
```

When i compile it with gcc -g -o filename filename.c, this is the output it gives me:

```
lab10.c:18:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token  {  ^
lab10.c:31:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token  {  ^
```

Comment: After `#define ARRAYLEN 8` you're missing the line with the name and signature of the function you're defining.

Comment: It should be `void PRINTBIN(unsigned char *p)`

Comment: *Note: This is not the error.* Don't put a semicolon at the end of a macro definition, only if you want to have it in its expansion. For example, in the current state of your source the line `PRINTBIN(b);` will be expanded to `printf(BYTETOBINARYPATTERN, BYTETOBINARY(b));;` in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two blocks of code:

```
{
    unsigned char final = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        final >>= 1;
        if (p[i] & 1)
            final |= 0x80;
    }
    return final;
}

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
         if (b0 & 1)
             p[i] |= 1;
         else
             p[i] &= 0xFE;
         b0 >>= 1;
    }
}
```

which are not part of anything. They're not part of a function, they're not part of a macro, they're not part of anything. C does not allow this. When I comment these two blocks of code out and compile your code I see that there are two functions - `setlsbs` and `getlsbs` - which are called in `main` but are not otherwise defined. Perhaps these two detached blocks of code were supposed to be these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, the problem is line 10 (or perhaps line 9)   Suggest looking at those two lines and looking at the error message to figure out what needs to be done to fix the problem.

also, this;

```
#define BYTETOBINARY(byte)  \
(byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x40 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x20 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0)
```

is doing nothing more that flip/flopping between returning 0 or 1,  Which is 
Not what the code needs to be doing.